# How to undo RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType()?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

After registering a .net remoting Service with `RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType()`, is there any way to undo this so that the application does not offer this Service anymore?

I checked this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.remoting.remotingconfiguration%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but surprisingly, there doesn't seem to be an UnregisterWellKnownServiceType-Method.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're registering your well-known type as a Singleton you could use:

```
RemotingServices.Disconnect(foo);
```

But first you would have to create the object then marshal it instead of using RegisterWellKnownServiceType:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
RemotingServices.Marshal(foo, uri);
```

This can't be done if you're registering your well-known type as SingleCall.

Comment: hmm. Is there a difference between RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType() and RemotingServices.Marshal() ? Why does RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType() exists when RemotingServices.Marshal can do the same + disconnect?

Comment: @marc40000 With RegisterWellKnownServiceType the object will not be created until a client asks for it first, you leave it up to the .NET framework to do the work. Marshal basically gives you more control and allows you to register an existing instance for remoting, and then disconnect when required.

Comment: I switched to RemotingServices.Marshal() in my Project. Now I'm experiencing the following issues: When the server runs for a while without any connection and then a Client tries to connect, it says that the server doesn't host the requested Services anymore. When I connect the client immediately after the server starts, it works. Is there a timeout somehow that removes the Mashaled Service automatically after a while?

Comment: @marc40000 I noticed you asked [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173631/remotingservices-marshalfoo-uri-only-works-for-a-short-period-of-time-how-to) so assume it's all working now.

Comment: Yes. I figured, it might be a valuable question on its own. Thank you again :)