# RemotingServices.Marshal(foo, uri) only works for a short period of time. How to keep it working?

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, remoting

When I do

```
RemotingServices.Marshal(foo, uri);
```

And the Client connects, everything works. When I wait for a few minutes and then try to connect the client, the Client throws a RemotingException: Object '{name of service}' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.

What happens here? Is there a timeout of some sort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid timeouts, you can add to your remoted object the following overridden method:

```
public override object InitializeLifetimeService(){
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this makes sure the remoteable object never dies (i.e. infinite lease-time) (By default, it would initially live for 5 minutes)